# Создание Rest api Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, api, hibernate, rest

Помогите не понятные ошибки, начал копаться в Spring Boot, и пытался создать Rest сайт, пробовал по трем гайдам и всегда у меня одни и те же ошибки которые решение в инете я найти не могу

```
@Entity
public class Message {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String name;
    private String text;
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" +
                "Id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
 
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("message")
public class MessageController {
    private final MessageRepo messageRepo;
 
    @Autowired
    public MessageController(MessageRepo messageRepo) {
        this.messageRepo = messageRepo;
    }
 
    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Message> getList()
    {
        return messageRepo.findAll();
    }
 
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public Message getMessage(@PathVariable("id") Message message){
        return message;
    }
 
    @PostMapping
    public Message postMessage(@RequestBody Message message)
    {
        return messageRepo.save(message);
    }
 
    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public Message putMessage(@PathVariable("id") Message messageFromDB , @RequestBody Message message)
    {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(message, messageFromDB,"id");
 
        return messageRepo.save(messageFromDB);
    }
 
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void deleteMessage(@PathVariable("id") Message message)
    {
       messageRepo.delete(message);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.io'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/messages&serverTimezone=UTC&
spring.datasource.username=mysql
spring.datasource.password=mysql
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

ошибки

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'messages&servertimezone=utc&'
```

Comment: Какие ошибки? Где они? Покажите!

Comment: Извиняюсь забыл

Comment: БД у вас есть - куда вы подключаетесь?

Comment: OpenService? Там создал бд

Answer (score 0):

В application.properties это свойство для mysql должно быть выглядеть как то так, в зависимости от порта и названия базы  -

```
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/youDB?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/messages?serverTimezone=UTC
```